# Access indexPath.row in button function Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, indexpath

I am trying to remove selected row with button. Therefore I need indexPath.row, I write value to global variable, but when I access it in button, it returns nil to me.

```
var selectedRow = ""

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedEvent = myConversationRows[indexPath.row]
    selectedRow = selectedEvent.id!
}

@IBAction func cancelConversation(_ sender: Any) {

    print("selected")
    print(self.selectedRow)
}
```

I guess that when I tap on button didSelectRowAt is not triggered. I have tried different methods, but none of them work.

[image]

Comment: First you need to select a row , second **selectedEvent.id** may be nil

Comment: Make a custom UITableViewCell, have a model object from your array in that cell, in the IBAction within the UITableViewCell, get the id and call the controller using a protocol. In the controller's protocol override, remove the id from the array and reload the tableView.

Comment: This should definitely be a custom cell, so in cellForRowAt addTarget to button. If you're interested, I can elaborate on this and write a solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an global variable!!!

Her is a easy way for that issue:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOURE_CELL_ID", for: indexPath) as? YOUT_CELL_CLASS {
        cell.youreButton.tag = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

and:

```
@IBAction func cancelConversation(_ sender: Any) {
    if let btn = sender as? UIButton {
        let row = btn.tag
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)], with: .bottom)
    }
}
```

why you don't use the ios delete swipe gesture?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("Deleted")


        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a bad way to do it.  Once a row is deleted, the tags in the rows below it will be off by 1.  Look at the duplicate answer for how to get the correct indexPath for the button.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! Silly 2017 me.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `selectedRow` as an `Int` and assign it a default value of `-1` meaning “not set”. Then, in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` put this line:

```
selectedRow = indexPath.row
```

In `cancelConversation()` put this:

```
if selectedRow != -1 {
    //...
}
```

Comment: selectedRow returns -1

Comment: This is an indicator that `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` has never been called. Did you correctly hook up the tableview delegate outlet?

Comment: didSelectRow will not work if his button has userInteractionEnabled ;) Thus my initial idea of hooking up a target to button so that only the button will respond to tap, not the entire row.